# how to add Paho-MQTT to android studio

Tags: android, mqtt, iot, paho, hivemq

I am trying to use Paho-MQTT in android studio. I referred to [this link](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service) 
and I should add the following to gradle files

**the link demands adding the following**:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
  }
}
```

the text did not specify which gradle file I use use "gradle-proj or gradle-app", so I tried both and in either cases i received errors such as

```
Error:(14, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2, build_9fu4g5nmegp97bvhjazm7s8o8$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure5@6dff2815] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\aba\AndroidStudioProjects\Test-PahoMQTT-1\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

please let me know which gradle file i should use "proj or app"? and how to add the previous code correctly to gradle?

**build.gradle app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alten.test_pahomqtt_1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
//compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2'
//provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.2-devpreview'
//provided 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:0.1-devpreview'

//compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') { exclude module: 'support-v4' }
compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar')
}
```

**build.gradle project**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()

    maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**current error**

[image]

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 6):

In your app you should add:

```
dependencies {
    . . .
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
}
```

In your proj:

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         . . .
         maven {
             url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
         }
     }
 }
```

dont forget about adding a service to your manifest under `application` tag:

```
<service
     android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"
     android:exported="false" />
```

Those two lines

```
compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar')
```

will not work until libs folder dont contains this jars. If you want to stick to this approach (copying jars) you can find them here:

https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.android.service/
https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/

Comment: i modified the post, what i added to build.gradle(app) is exactly as what you posted BUT i added the extension `.jar` when i use the same command without `.jar`i doesnt work. moreover, please have a look at the attched screen shot , it shows that I can not use `MqttService`..maybe because my own package..please let me know how to fix these errors

Comment: as I see you are trying to add jars from libs folder `compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar')` so it will look for file `org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.2.jar'` in your libs folder. The code which I have posted will look for this file in repositories (definied in project gradle), and it should find it in one of them `maven { url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/" }` which we manually added

Comment: for both dependencies you posted i receive the following:Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0

Comment: updated my answer: in proj gradle try `url https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/` instead of  `url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots`

Comment: if you have checked the modification i added to the post, you would have realised that i already tried `url`you provided..anyway, it does not work

Comment: and what error will you get if you uncommnent those two lines `//compile 'org.eclipse.paho: ...` and remove `compile files('libs/org.eclipse.paho ...` lines ?

Comment: it is : Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0